# react-scripts Vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-scripts

It could be pretty basic but I was not able to find any convenient answer. I am developing a react js app. I am checking vulnerability and security problems in that point. One of the library I used is react-scripts. The problem is latest version of react-scripts have a lot of vulnerability problem. Can I directly change dependency version? Or what library will be a good alternative to react-scripts.

Answer (score 2):

`react-scripts` is no longer being actively maintained.  It is a package that is being [Create-React-App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), that was [deprecated earlier this year](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13072).

I recommend you consider going to a newer build system [such as Vite](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13072).

Comment: But I already develop my project with it. How can I transfer it?

Comment: Converting from CRA to Vite is a pretty simple move, unless you have made dramatic changes to the webpack, babel and other "bundling" capabilities in your app.  Mostly it involves: (1) create a new React project with vite (`npx create-vite`), (2) make sure the vite project runs with `npm run dev`, (3) copy your `src` folder from your CRA project into the new Vite project, (4) try running your project again `npm run dev`.  Most errors are easily resolved with a web search.